# CSS Stylesheet linking wrong in Wordpress across entire site

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Ok, I have a feeling I've really done it this time. I've developed a Wordpress site locally and then transferred it to my remote server. I did a search and replace on the database using the script.

Now, I go into my site on the remote server and the HTML is good, but the CSS stylesheet is not linking properly.

Here is how it appears when I view source:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="www.fairchildwebsolutions.com/jesusandg/wp-content/themes/Sky/style.css" />
```

Now when I click on the link in source, I am directed to this:

```
www.fairchildwebsolutions.com/jesusandg/www.fairchildwebsolutions.com/jesusandg/wp-content/themes/Sky/style.css
```

Obviously, one too many domain names in there, so the file cannot be found. My question now is, how do I go back and do a search and replace on this to remove the extra domain without messing things up even worse?

Comment: Sep. 2018 the same issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://www.fairchildwebsolutions.com/jesusandg/wp-content/themes/Sky/style.css" />
```

Without the http:// it thinks its a local link not direct.

Wordpress can also link to the stylesheet or theme directory:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo( 'stylesheet_url' ); ?>" />
```

Here is some more information on the function to call out the theme directory: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory

Answer (score 0):

when you add the stlyesheets in your functions.php try to stay away from using exact links and instead use the get_template_directory_uri (or something like that i can't remember the syntax exactly. it's referenced here [Wordpress codex for template directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory)

Answer (score 0):

Add `http://` to the beginning of your style `href`. Alternatively, since it appears you are on the same domain, simply modify the `href` to be the following:

```
href="/jesusandg/wp-content/themes/Sky/style.css"
```

The former is an absolute path. The latter is an absolute path relative to your domain root.

Answer (score 0):

Your stylesheet call is missing its `http://` at the beginning of the `href`.  This means the browser interprets it as a relative path not an absolute one and breaks the link.

What does your stylesheet call say (probably in `header.php`)?  It should be something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/style.css" />
```

The `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` call returns the absolute path of the theme directory.

If it's not in `header.php` it's probably referenced in `functions.php` using the `wp_enqueue_script()` function.  Same deal - use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` or one of the several template tags that do the same thing and make sure that is used to build the url to the stylesheet rather than defining it explicitly.